# About js to Get background Color

Tags: javascript, html

i have a question about to get the X id by 
document.getElementById("X").style.backgroundColor 
this is my HTML:

```
<div id ="X" class="main-sidebar text-white "> 

      </div>
```

CSS like:

```
.main-sidebar{
background-color: #343a40;
width:10%;
height:100%;
display:block;
position: absolute;
left:0px;
/*top:0px;*/
}
```

But when I use document.getElementById("X").style.backgroundColor in js i get NULL value...

Comment: PS. if i change <div id ="X" class="main-sidebar text-white ">  to <div id ="X" class="main-sidebar text-white "style="background-color: #343a40;"> i can get background-color

Comment: `.style` only accesses the element's *inline* styles: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Comment: If that's the case, maybe try to put your document.getElementbyId inside document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

That will make sure you wait for the html/css objects and properties to load.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `style` refers to the inline `style` attribute in your HTML. If you want to get the `style` that's set via CSS only, you will need to use `computedStyles`.

```js
const elem = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]; // get element
const styles = window.getComputedStyle(elem); // get computed style of element
console.log(styles.getPropertyValue('background-color')); // get specific attribute
```

```css
p {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Hi!</p>
```

Comment: get it Thx you !

Comment: @HughHarlequin Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using computed styles:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("X")).backgroundColor
```

Answer (score 1):

`.style` Will get or set the **inline** style of an element.
In your case, the style for `.main-sidebar` is in a .css file.
What you can do is use `getComputedStyle()`:
`getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("X")).backgroundColor // #343a40`